# Vbscript can't modify component table of MSI?

Tags: windows, vbscript, installation, windows-installer

I try to write vbscript, to remove the duplicated component GUID entry in component table of a MSI.
But I always get 80004005 error, MSI API error.

Does it mean vbscript can't modify/delete on component table?

I do know Transform can.

my code snippet:

```
    DeleteQuery = "delete from component where component.component="+comp
    Set DeleteView = Msmdatabase.OpenView(DeleteQuery)
    DeleteView.Execute
    DeleteView.Close
```

The error happens during OpenView

thanks,
William L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Windows Installer documentation, specifically the section [SQL Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372021(VS.85).aspx)

> Table names are limited to 31
>   characters. For more information, see
>   Table Names. **Table and column names
>   are case-sensitive.** SQL keywords are
>   not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Ooopss.    I found out my error.
The vbscript is not case-sensitive, SQL is not case-sensitive,

But Table and column names are case-sensitive!!!!